# Error whie install psycopg2 on ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: django, ubuntu, server, psycopg2

> error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
>       ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/mosi/venv/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import
>   sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
>   '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-im9_x6c8/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';
>   **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-im9_x6c8/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   install --record /tmp/pip-record-jyz3lis6/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/mosi/venv/include/site/python3.6/psycopg2 Check the logs for
>   full command output.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with psycopg2 some time too. Resolved it just by replacing `psycopg2` with appropriate version of `psycopg2-binary`.

Answer (score 0):

It may occur due to missing Postgres and/or Python libraries. Make sure you have essentials:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpq-dev 
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev
```